# React Beautiful DND example without react-window

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

This is the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-virtual-list-board-vgvzt?file=/src/index.js) that I like, because of hooks. But I don't want use `react-window` package. Tried to remove it, ended up with no luck. How can I make this example minimalist like [simple board example](https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.app/?path=/story/board--simple)

Answer (score 0):

There is this [`react-dnd package`](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about) that could feet your needs. It does not use react-window and the doc seems up to date (Also use hooks). I would give it a try. At least a quick look at the doc to see if examples fit your requirement.